# Adding columns to data

Tags: text-processing, awk

Inputfile

```
926982133
5031919
001112986
44241218
041783978
978309
037844776
19919117
067705805
12432083
```

Outputfile:

```
0000000001|926982133|201702|10
0000000002|005031919|201702|10
0000000003|001112986|201702|10
0000000004|044241218|201702|10
0000000005|041783978|201702|10
0000000006|000978309|201702|10
0000000007|037844776|201702|10
0000000008|019919117|201702|10
0000000009|067705805|201702|10
0000000010|012432083|201702|10
```

i want like this output how i will get in awk

Comment: is that 3rd and 4th fields are static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ printf("%.10d|%.9d|201702|10\n", NR, $1) }' file
0000000001|926982133|201702|10
0000000002|005031919|201702|10
0000000003|001112986|201702|10
0000000004|044241218|201702|10
0000000005|041783978|201702|10
0000000006|000978309|201702|10
0000000007|037844776|201702|10
0000000008|019919117|201702|10
0000000009|067705805|201702|10
0000000010|012432083|201702|10
```

This takes the input data, and adds `|`-delimited fields to it while also reformatting the numbers read as zero-filled 9-digit numbers.  The first field is formatted as a zero-filled 10-digit number but using the current line number as data, while the last two fields are static.